# How to fix thread or handle error in Swift?

Tags: swift, thread-safety, coreml

I can't get rid of an error in the program using Core ML image recognize!

My code is basically debugged and works with a large number of files, but on 421 files the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error occurs (and I changed the order of processing files to eliminate the problem of broken files)
I have already translated all potentially dangerous objects into singletons to avoid leaks, debugged and tidied the sqlite database, rewritten the code using the recommended generateCGImagesAsynchronously operator to get a picture from a video file, everything is cleaned up and works without leaks, but the error still occurs
Directly the code for extracting text objects is taken from the network and slightly upgraded, maybe there is a problem with it?, help!

```
CreateAltModel3.shared.handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: inputImage!)
        CreateAltModel3.shared.request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: CreateAltModel3.shared.visionModel!) { [weak self] req3, error in
            output_handler(req3.results) }
        
        do {try CreateAltModel3.shared.handler!.perform([CreateAltModel3.shared.request!])} catch {print ("hadler3 error - request3")}
```

here is the code for the output_handler function

```
            func output_handler(_ results: [Any]?) {
        guard let results = results as? [VNClassificationObservation]
            else {return}
        for class1 in results {
            if (class1.confidence > 0.05) {  // Only show greater than 5%
                let fileID = filesArray[currentFileIndex]?.index
                if percentRecogn <= Int(round(class1.confidence*100)) {
                    findKeyStr = (class1.identifier + " " + String(round(class1.confidence*100)) + "%")
                    resultKeyStr.0 = Int64(fr)
                    let comma = (resultKeyStr.1 == "") ? "" : ", "
                    let cutDubbing = (resultKeyStr.1 == class1.identifier) ? resultKeyStr.1 : resultKeyStr.1 + comma + class1.identifier
                    resultKeyStr.1 = cutDubbing
                    resultKeyStr.2 = Int64(fileID!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but the error as I understand it occurs after exiting this function

on the next line of code
[image]

more code to spread does not make sense because I will only confuse you with extra information, I will only add that this code works in a loop in the global stream and outputs information to the label and ImageView in the main stream as expected, and everything seems to be debugged but I can not understand the nature of the error, perhaps something related to streams but there is not even an idea where to dig)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot (or at least should not) use a single `VNCoreMLRequest` from multiple threads at a time.

Comment: but I also divided requests (like request1 request2) and that's why I put an object of the VNCoreMLRequest type in a singleton to work with a single instance, do you suggest working with this object in the main thread or deleting the global queue?

Comment: As of iOS 14 Apple says you should use Core ML models from a single thread or queue only. If you want to use multiple threads, you should make more than one instance of the MLModel object (and thus of VNCoreMLModel).

Comment: am create macOS app

Comment: Same thing, it doesn't matter whether you're on iOS or macOS.

Comment: I put the critical code in the global queue and update only the controls in the main queue, but nothing has changed,, need help fixing a possible stack overflow

Comment: trouble fixed, its really thread problems